# Select does not render options on dynamic fetching of options

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

```
HTML:
<select (focus)="onFocus()">
    <option *ngFor="let c of myDropDown">{{c}}</option>
</select>
<input [hidden]="myDropDown !=='two'"type="text">

Component:
onFocus() {
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').subscribe(val => {
      console.log(val)
      this.myDropDown = val;
    })
  }
```

On Focus of Select, I am trying to fetch the options by making a service call, but somehow the dropdown does not open and I have to click twice.

StackBlitz Link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-example-3jvz1h?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

Change your html to this:

```
<select (mouseover)="onFocus" (focus)="onFocus()">
   <option *ngFor="let c of myDropDown" [value]="c.id">{{c.title}}</option>
</select>
```

then add a hook using `OnInit`:

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.onFocus()
}
```

Comment: I understand that this works, but I want to know why the above code does not work with just a focus event.

Comment: Actually focus event works. try to click your `tab` button and it works. Maybe what you need is `mouseover` event

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to generally use onFocus since you want to load initially you can put the service call inside the constructor and load the options as follows,

```
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
   this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').subscribe(val => {
        this.myDropDown = val;
    });

 }
```

[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-example-ceberd?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but should not the above code work without initializing the data. Why should we need to initialize it again in the constructor?

Comment: it wont work without initializing the data. the problem above was why do you need focus?

Comment: I have multiple such rows and for each row based on the data, I need to make a service call to get the dropdown options. so I chose to fetch the data on focus event, so technically on focus we are fetching the data and the component is rendering the template html as well, but I could not see that data on the select dropdown ui

Comment: If you are doing that it's going to heavily affect your user experience as you load the data on focus. I will suggest you to load the data initially and bind it in the component